# Eclipse - How to import a local source file into the same folder?

Tags: java, eclipse

I wanted to import a file which was originally not imported into the source folder in Eclipse

What I did was:

1. I tried placing the file directory into a source file folder, which obviously did not work.
2. Then I right-clicked on `folder->import->File System` and tried to import that file, but eclipse then complains `Source is in the hierarchy of destination`. 
   What I did in the end was move the source file out of that folder, then import it back in from a different path, which I find really redundant.

What's the best way to include a file like that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: a simple *.java file? how about copy/paste?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can not import into the same folder bcz no OS allow to create multiple folder of the same name in same parent. instead, you put the folder being imported somewhere else, and while importing it to workspace, check the option to "copy into workspace"

Comment: what do you mean by OS not allowing to create folder with same names? Are you implying that when importing, eclipse creates a brand new folder, moves all the existing files into the new folder, and then add the new file being imported?

Comment: no, it creates new folder and keep new data in it, why should it move older files first? wastage of resource.

Comment: I'm still not getting the point. What happens when Eclipse tries to "Import" a file? My intuition is it simply copies the file and adds a pointer in its build path that points to the file. If that's the case why should Eclipse even want to create a new folder? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @turtlesoup because I add the source files to the folder elsewhere and need continue use eclipse after that.

Answer (score 35):

If you added (outside of Eclipse) a file to a source directory for your project, you should be able to get the file to show up in Eclipse by right-clicking your source folder in the Eclipse Package Explorer and selecting "Refresh" .

Comment: no, it wont. for eclipse to know that any directory is a project directory, it should be imported properly, so that there will be an entry in workspace's metadata.

Comment: If you re-read the question, @Jimster already has the source directory imported as a project directory.  He's trying to bring a file *already in that directory* into his project, which implies it was added externally and will appear after a refresh on the source directory.

Comment: OP said "Source...which was originally not imported", it means source was not imported.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Next question would of course then be why, when you "Run" a project in Eclipse, it does not autorefresh the workspace in the first place!

Comment: Worked like a charm. Awesome!

This should be marked as the solution.

Answer (score 4):

As of October 2017, using Eclipse Oxygen 2017.1, I found that to accomplish what the OP wanted to do is not to what your natural instincts tell you to do.

In my case, I originally developed the code on Computer A in directory c:\projects\abc\ and copied the directory to computer B in directory c:\projects\abc\ outside of Eclipse.

Instead of

Import / General / File System /

which gives the error the OP mentioned, you instead need to:

Import / General / Projects from Folder or Archive /

When the dialog opens, point the "Import source:" to your already-present-where-it-needs-to-be directory (example: c:\projects\abc).

I left everything else to the defaults.

Click Finish.

When I return to Project Explorer, I did NOT need to Refresh the window.  The project automatically showed up.

Answer (score 2):

You've set up your Eclipse workspace and source code to be in the same folder i.e. the folder where your Eclipse .metadata resides is the same place as all your folders of code.  Ideally, the folder for Eclipse's metadata should be somewhere else.  (I did the same thing myself and then ran into all sorts of problems).

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @user3785010 answer, I found that using `Import > General > Existing Projects into Workspace` worked for me with Eclipse Platform Version: 2021-09 (4.21).

When I tried `Import > General > Projects from Folder or Archive`, I pressed Finish and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

1. File -> Import the file from File System into the project folder
2. Add it to the Build Path

It was added with the relative path in the project.

It shows Ok in Java Build Path and in .classpath, though [*] the project folder in Eclipse does not show the imported file.

Comment: I edited to turn this into a partial answer, i.e. something that at least provides the solution for one part of the problem. If you want to ask a question please delete this and create a question of your own - or use your commenting privilege.